# git-flow release finish rejected because develop is ahead

Tags: git, github

I am using git-flow to manage our release process.  after doing git-flow init, etc., I create a release candidate branch with

```
git-flow release start <label>
```

All is fine. While I am testing the RC branch other developers are usually working on the next release in the develop branch.  When the RC branch is declared good to go, I use

```
git-flow release finish –p <label>
```

but then I sometimes (not always) get an error

```
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to <repo-address>
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
Could not push to develop from origin.
```

Naturally, it is going to be behind the tip since the developers were working on develop. Should I be telling git-flow not to merge back into develop?  If so, how? If not, what is the correct work-flow?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to merge back into `develop`, but before you do, you will want to pull from develop. From your description, it looks like git-flow does not automatically do this, yet it is automatically *pushing* `develop`, which is odd. Anyway, I would make the following your workflow:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout <release-branch>
git-flow release finish –p <label>
```

Comment: It seems like git-flow doesn’t do the right steps.  See article 

[https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac](here)

git-flow release does this:

    git checkout master
    git merge --no-ff release/1.2.0
    git tag -a 1.2.0
    git checkout develop
    git merge --no-ff release/1.2.0
    git branch -d release/1.2.0